# How can I trigger a search with a minimum character count in rust tantivy?

Tags: rust, tantivy

Currently, Tantivy provides search results when the query has at least 4 characters. However, I want to trigger the search even with just one character. I found something called MoreLikeThisQuery in the documentation, but I am still unable to figure out how to use it.

https://teaclave.apache.org/api-docs/crates-enclave/tantivy/query/struct.MoreLikeThisQuery.html